# How to divide a Matrix by another matrix in Scala

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, matrix-inverse

I have initialized two matrices (X and Y) in Scala as follows,

```
 var x = ofDim[Int](a1,b1)
 var y = ofDim[Int](a2,b2)
```

x,y,a1,a2,b1 and b2 are variables.
 and now i need to decide X by Y (X/Y). How can achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean elmentwise division or `XY^(-1)` matrix multiplication?

Comment: @Psidom, I mean, if A, X, Y are Matrices, and If AX = Y and A and Y are known matrices, so I need to get X matrix.I think it should be XY^(-1).

Comment: You may want to check the breeze library, it implements quite a few linear algebra with Vector and Matrices. But if you want to deal with rdds, it's another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is other approach that use Apache Commons. However, it is important observe that the division operation applies multiplication and inversion operations and, some matrix are inversable and others no: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix

The following example applies the library Apache Commons (**Study.scala**):

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear._

object Study {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

     val xArray = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(3.0, 4.0))
     val yArray = Array(Array(1.0, 2.0), Array(3.0, 4.0))

     val x = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(xArray)
     val y = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(yArray)

     val yInverse = new LUDecomposition(y).getSolver().getInverse();
     val w = x.multiply(yInverse)

     for(i <- 0 until w.getRowDimension())
         for(j <- 0 until w.getColumnDimension())
             println(w.getEntry(i, j))

    }
}
```

> Tip: If you intend to use the scala console, you need to specify the classpath ...

```
 scala -classpath .../commons-math3/3.2/commons-math3-3.2.jar
```

> ... in the scala session you load the algorithm ...

```
  :load .../Study.scala
```

> ... and the results come out calling the main function of Study (approximation can be applied) ...

```
 scala> Study.main(null)
```

> 0.99 / 1.11E-16 / 0.0 / 1.02

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix, inv}

val mx = new DenseMatrix(a1, b1, x.transpose.flatten)
val my = new DenseMatrix(a2, b2, y.transpose.flatten)

mx * inv(my)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The library Beeze, as mecioned in other responses, is necessary. You can install it using SBT or Maven

The Breeze project can be download from [GitHub](https://github.com/scalanlp/breeze.git)

This is the Maven approach:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>breeze_2.10</artifactId> <!-- or 2.11 -->
    <version>0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

> The code ...

```
import breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix

object Division {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        var a1 = 10
        var a2 = 11
        var b1 = 12
        var b2 = 13

       //var x = Array.ofDim[Int](a1,b1)
       //var y = Array.ofDim[Int](a2,b2)

       var x = DenseMatrix(a1,b1)
       var y = DenseMatrix(a2,b2)

       var result = x/y
       print(result)
  }
}
```